# Data passing from HTML text input to python script

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am creating a web scraping application, using Django, which scrapes the imdb website and lists the movie names based on what users types in the text field[suppose if user types 'b', it lists all the movie names starting with letter 'b']
I have a html text input and a button.

```
<body>
    <h1>The IMDB Scraper</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Iron Man..">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</body>
```

I also have a python script which scrapes the data from the website, using the hardcoded keyword.

I want to send the text input data to this python script when the button is pressed and process this data and send send the result hack to the same HTML page for display.

Comment: What have you tried till now ?

Comment: I have accessed the form input using jQuery, when the button is pressed, and now i want to run a python script right after the text input is accessed and display the response from this script on the same page where the form is.